# Unable to group the two Middlewares

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud, middleware

I am trying to implement 3 user types in to my application, I am using the default Auth of Laravel.

I created 2 extra middlewares to acheive the to extra user(admin & Districtlogin) conditions along with user approval middleware, and using the default for laravel user

> Admin middleware

```
class Admin
{
   tion handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('login')->with('error','You have not admin access');
        }
}
```

> Districtlogin Middleware

```
class Districtlogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin == 2) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

> One additional middleware to check if the user is approved

```
class ApproveUser
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->row_status == 1)
    {
        return $next($request);

    }
            return redirect('/userapprove');

    }
```

I am able to redirect them based on the login

> Auth/LoginController

```
 public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1 && Auth::user()->row_status == 1) {
            return '/adminindex';
        } elseif (Auth::user()->row_status == 0) {
            return '/userapprove';
        } elseif (Auth::user()->isAdmin == 2 && Auth::user()->row_status == 1) {
            return '/districtindex';
        }
        return '/engineerdashboard';
    }
```

Here is my

> kernel.php

entry

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
'districtlogin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Districtlogin::class,
'userapprove' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApproveUser::class,
```

I would like to group the admin and Districtlogin middleware.

I am using CRUD, I would like Districtlogin to have access to few controllers - index,store,update

When I try to group the middleware, I am redirected back to the login screen. Neither of the middleware works

Here's what I tried,

1)

```
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {

    //Admin Dashboard
    Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController')->middleware('districtlogin');
    Route::get('adminindex/new', 'AdminindexController@admindashboard');
});
```

2)

```
Route::middleware(['admin','districtlogin'])->group(function () {

    //Admin Dashboard
    Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController');
    Route::get('adminindex/new', 'AdminindexController@admindashboard');

});
```

3)

```
 Route::middleware(['admin',''])->group(function () {

        //Admin Dashboard
        Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController');
        Route::get('adminindex/new', 'AdminindexController@admindashboard');

        Route::middleware(['districtlogin'])->group(function () {
        Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController');

           });

    });
```

But when I use the 'OR' condition, I am able to access the pages

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin' OR 'districtlogin']], function () {

    //Admin Dashboard
    Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController');
    Route::get('adminindex/new', 'AdminindexController@admindashboard');
});
```

The controllers are accessible by both the middlewares. But how do I limit the Crud functions based on the middleware.

I am completely clueless on how to achieve it.

Comment: your two middlewares are incompatible to have them together. Each one checks for a conditoon NOT MET by the other, so there is NO COMMON GROUND in order to group them together. Either change your middleware to have some common ground (for example `Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin > 1`) or use different routes for each different middleware

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @NikosM. I will create new routes for the other middleware :)

Comment: @NikosM. Could you please brief me on "Either change your middleware to have some common ground(for example Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin > 1)".

Comment: sorry I meant `Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin >= 1` this includes both cases where isAdmin = 1 or isAdmin = 2 so there is a common ground and middlewares can be grouped together, actually one middleware with above condition is enough and THEN in your code check if isAdmin is 1 or 2. But better have different routes if you need very different functionality for each user type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete answer is:

The two middlewares are **incompatible with each other**, they have **no common ground**. Where one succeeds the other fails and redirects to login page.

So this explains the first part of your question.

The second part is that `Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin' OR 'districtlogin']]` .. is meaningless as regards to configuring middleware. it is equivalent to `Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']]`.. since the expression `'admin' OR 'districtlogin'` always evaluates to first operand. Plus it is misleading as Laravel **does not support having middlewares one or the other** it is meaningless expression.

**The solution:**

**Either use one middleware** that can support both options, for example:

```
class AdminOrDistrictlogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin >= 1 ) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

`entry:`

```
'adminOrdistrict' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminOrDistrictlogin::class,
'userapprove' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApproveUser::class,
```

`routes`:

```
Route::middleware(['adminOrdistrict'])->group(function () {

    //Admin or District Dashboard, distignuish later in your code
    Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController');
    Route::get('adminindex/new', 'AdminindexController@admindashboard');

});
```

And in your controllers and views refine further by checking `Auth::user()->isAdmin` value for distinguishing between simple admins or districts

**Or**, if the functionality is very different between simple admins and districts, **create new and different routes** for `admin` and `district` and use each middleware in the appropriate route group for each type of user.

For example:

```
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {

    //Admin Dashboard
    Route::resource('adminindex', 'AdminindexController');
    Route::get('adminindex/new', 'AdminindexController@admindashboard');

});

Route::middleware(['districtlogin'])->group(function () {

    //District Dashboard
    Route::resource('districtindex', 'DistrictindexController');
    Route::get('districtindex/new', 'DistrictindexController@admindashboard');

});
```

Choice is yours :)